# hack mini-game tips and tricks to succeed even with low skill for EYE Divine Cybermancy?

Tags: eye-divine-cybermancy

I am using all settings at max difficulty on this hardcore cyberpunk game.

Is there any way to successfully hack even not having high hack skill? what order we must click the buttons and how?

Bonus: And a way to make the hack sounds less painful?

Answer (score 2):

I will answer what I already know/do, but I still look for better tips :)

1) keep clicking on mask until enemy (using overload) lower it''s own defenses til 0.
  2) click 2 times on shield and one on mask til you up defense to 300 (enemy will spend time on overloading after your mask, this is the trick step).
  3) click 2 or 3 times on overflow, and then 1 on attack.
  4) Repeat from step (2)

Btw, if the AI one day gets patched to not lose time on overloading, this trick may not work anymore :>

I modified these files lowering their volume and pitch using `audacity`, so I dont have to change the PC volume using media keyboard controls, during hack mini-game:

```
sound/player/hack/hack_attack.wav  
sound/player/hack/hack_inject.wav
```

(I dont know if I can upload them here as a game mod tho... but you can change them to anything else you have, even making sounds with your mouth xD)